# big O time complexity recurrence relation

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Can someone please explain how the time complexity of this algorithm is O(n) using recurrence relation.

```py
def exercise2(N):
    count = 0 
    i = N
    while ( i > 0 ):
        for j in range(0,i): 
            count = count + 1
        i = i//2
```

Comment: [How do I ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822. It is [not possible to just "explain"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278797) something about the code, because we have no way to know *why* you do not already understand it. Instead: show us *your* reasoning. If you don't believe that the algorithm is O(n), then try to prove a different result.

Comment: Hint: how many times will `count = count + 1` happen, the first time through the loop? How many times will it happen the second time through the loop, approximately? The third time? What result do you get if you add up all those iterations? (Hint for the hint: do you know what a *geometric sequence* is? Do you understand how to sum them?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For positive  the number of executions of `count = count + 1` is representative of the complexity, as the other lines of code don't execute significantly more times.

The recurrence relation can use the first iteration of the outer loop: that represents  iterations of the inner loop. The loop continues for /2, and that can be represented with a recursive case:

=  + <sub>/2</sub>

The base case is when  is zero, in which case there is no iteration of the loop, or we could also set it when  is one, in which case there is just one iteration of the loop:

<sub>1</sub> = 1

So this relation expands as follows:

=  + /2 + /4 + ... + 1 = ∑<sub><sub>=0..</sub></sub> ( / 2)

This is a [geomatric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1/2_%2B_1/4_%2B_1/8_%2B_1/16_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) that -- when we perform *integer divisions* and  is a power of 2 -- is equal to 2−1 and otherwise is not greater than 2−1.

So we can say the algorithm has a complexity of O(2) = O()